# How to hide logo conversation actions on google app?

Tags: actions-on-google

When I created my app there was a toolbar on top. I see other apps do not have that bar. How do I hide it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to remove that banner, as it is used to tell the user that they are conversing with your Action.

Comment: It is indeed very useful to the user! As many user wouldn't know that they're still in an Action.